# Actions: Create and View button disappeared in cugar crm in custom modules

Tags: content-management-system, crm, sugarcrm

I have added several new custom modules in SugarCRM via the module builder. Now the problem is, that in the menu tab under Actions, Create ... and View ...  disappeared. Is it possible getting these two buttons back again? Thanks for help!

```
Normally and still in default modules it looks like this:

       When opening e.g. Accounts:

             Actions: | Create ACCOUNTS | View ACCOUNTS | Import ACCOUNTS

In all custom modules it looks like this:
       When opening e.g. Suppliers (custom created module):
             Actions: | Import
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a `Menu.php` file in your module? If so what is the contents?

Try this on 6.3.0RC2 as well. Updating should resolve the issue.

If you still see the problem, can you add a bug for this at http://bugs.sugarcrm.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! There is no menu.php file in any of the custom generated modules (Path: \sugarcrm\modules\DEVICES\)!

Comment: What version of Sugar are you on?

Comment: I've got Version 6.3.0beta6 (Build 6874) directly from the official sugar website!

Comment: Please try this on 6.3.0RC2 as well. If you still see the problem, can you add a bug for this at http://bugs.sugarcrm.com